# api get request on a header.ejs file with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, header, ejs

i'd like to display data from an endpoint on a header.ejs file which will be shown on all the routed files (e.g. "/", "/news" "/dogs")

here's my app.js code:

```
// GET API REQUEST
var url = 'https://url.tld/api/';
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
        return parsedData;
    }
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index.ejs", {parsedData: parsedData});   
    });
```

the code from header.ejs:

```
<li>Active players: <span><%= parsedData["players"] %></span></li>
```

I get a parsedData is undefined error and I dont know how to get it done in any way. I want to show the active players and a server status in the navbar. What's a common practice to achive this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should solve this problem using middleware.

From the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in):

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.
>
> Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:
>
> - Execute any code.
> - Make changes to the request and the response objects.
> - End the request-response cycle.
> - Call the next middleware function in the stack.

Middleware always take the request, the response, and the function `next` as arguments. You do whatever you need to do, and then call `next` to move onto the next thing on the list.

So, for example, if you wanted to write a simple middleware that would log the time every time the app received a request, you'd say something like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(Date.now())
  next()
})
```

So in your case, maybe you'd say:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // stuff
  request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    //stuff
    res.locals.parsedData = parsedData
  })
})
```

And then in your `res.render`, you'd say

```
res.render('index.ejs', {parsedData: res.locals.parsedData})
```

Again from the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals):

> [res.locals is] An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is identical to app.locals.

If you know you'll only need to make this request once, attach the parsed data to `app.locals` instead, and then in the middleware, add a check to see if `app.locals.parsedData` exists before you run the request.

Hope this helps!